# Find a GridView row programmatically

Tags: asp.net, gridview

The row has a LinkButton that when clicked needs to highlight the row.

Code so far:

```
protected void linkbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton l = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow g = (GridViewRow)l.Parent; // what is the correct way to do this?
    //g.Style etc etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all set the "CommandName" property of LinkButton to "select",
then in the selectedIndexChanging event of gridview write below code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count;i++ )
            GridView1.Rows[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
 GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cornsilk;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the RowCommand event of the GridView instead of the Click event of the LinkButton.

Then you can have a `CommandName` on the LinkButton such as "HighlightRow" and do something like the following:

```
Select Case e.CommandName
  Case "HighlightRow"
    e.item.row.attributes("class") = "highlight"
End Select
```

Sorry its in VB.NET and not C#

Answer (score 0):

1.) Set Command Name Property to "Select"

2.) Change style either on code behind as shown by @Raymond or give set Cssclass attribute for 
SelectedRowStyle of gridview to CssClass="selecterowstyle"

.selectedRowstyle
{
background-color:#EAEAEA;
}